# Unwanted random iterator in For-Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to create a function for generating a set number (numbersToChoose) of values between two other values (startFrom and stopAt) but for some reason the iterator (?) in the second for-loop (line 7), in this case a seems to be randomly generated even though I don't see any reason for that.

```
def chooseRandomNumbers(numbersToChoose, startFrom, stopAt):

 numbers = [(randrange(startFrom, stopAt))]  # initialize empty list of numbers

 for n in range(numbersToChoose-1):  # choose random number from 1 to 49 a total of 7 times
    x = randrange(startFrom, stopAt+1)
    for a in numbers:  # check for already existing elements in "numbers"
        if x == numbers[a]:  # if new random number already exists in "numbers" discard and run loop again
            n -= 1  # decreases n by 1 so a new (hopefully not already existing) number can be generated
        else:  # generated numbers does not exist in "numbers" yet
            numbers.append(x)  # appends randomly chosen number to list "numbers"

 return numbers  # returns said list "numbers"
```

Any advice on how to deal with this is greatly appreciated.
Also please tell me if possible anything else bad in the code (just started python).

Comment: What is the output you are getting and what was expected as the output? If you can provide such kinds of details, it would be easier for us to help you

Comment: `numbers` is created using `randrange()`, so why _shouldn't_ `a` be *randomly generated?*

Comment: @AnandSKumar because of a being random and always >= 1 (in this case) it tried to access not existing parts of the list (out of range)

Comment: @boardrider I thought that a in the for-loop will start at 0 and following that, that numbers[a] would access the first item in numbers[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to check if generated number is already in the list is wrong.
`for a in numbers`, in this loop, you are using `numbers[a]` while `a` is a member of list but not the index of the member.
 use `in` to test if a number is in list:

from random import randrange

```
def chooseRandomNumbers(numbersToChoose, startFrom, stopAt):
     numbers = []
     for n in range(numbersToChoose):
        x = randrange(startFrom, stopAt+1)
        if not x in numbers:
            numbers.append(x)
        else:
            n -= 1
     return numbers
```

or simply:

```
from random import sample
def chooseRandomNumbers(numbersToChoose, startFrom, stopAt):
    return sample(range(startFrom,stopAt+1),numbersToChoose)
```

Comment: Thanks alot
Makes the whole thing way easier

Comment: @Ylonec , You are welcome, I've updated the answer adding a more simpler one-liner , check it :)

Comment: `n -= 1` what does it do?

Comment: @NizamMohamed , If the random number we generated in the current iteration is already in the list `numbers` , we'd waste an iteration and the number of elements in the final list would be less than expected, so we decrement the loop counter to compensate the wasted iteration :)

Comment: does it do what you say it does?

Comment: @NizamMohamed , It does

Comment: @ylonec don't accept an answer before checking if it works.

Comment: @NizamMohamed , don't say don't accepts without pointing what's wrong

Comment: @NizamMohamed I tried both solutions and both worked for me